# Pattern Regex in java

Tags: java

I am trying to implement pattern regx using java and upto some extent i did it as well but i want a small help i.e i am trying to match two pattern i.e Name and Date(which is coming from an input txt file) and i am storing both of them in an arraylist and trying to get the output like **Name ; Date** and that too i am able achieve it but the output that i want is not what i am excepting, maybe from this example you will get a clear of  what i actually want :

Input File :

```
Hey my name is alex and my date of birth is 19-may-1999
Hey my name is raman and my date of birth is 21-may-1999
Hey my name is ali and my date of birth is 
Hey my name is jack and my date of birth is 23-may-1999
```

Output i am getting on console:

```
alex ; 19-may-1999
raman ; 21-may-1999
ali ; 23-may-1999

Output that i want :
alex ; 19-may-1999
raman ; 21-may-1999
ali ; 
jack ; 23-may-1999
```

since ali's date of birth is not mentioned i want blank space at the place of his date of birth

***Please Note few points :***
-Don't worry about the pattern its fine as the input file data is not something that i am passing in actual that is just an example to show you what i really want to achieve
-Please let me know if my question is ambiguous and need some edit.

Thanks in advance!!

**Here is my snippet**

```
    public static void getFinalResult(String filepath)
{

    List<String> StreamMatcher = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> DateMatcher = new ArrayList<String>();
    int index = 0;
    try
    {

        FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fstream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String strLine;
        while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)
        {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[0-9]{1,2}-[a-zA-Z]{3}-[0-9]{4}");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine);
            while (m.find())
            {
                String inp1 = m.group(0);
                DateMatcher.add(inp1);

            }
        }
        br.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)

    {
        System.err.println("Error: " + ex.getMessage());
    }

    try
    {
        FileInputStream fstream1 = new FileInputStream(filepath);
        DataInputStream in1 = new DataInputStream(fstream1);

        BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in1));
        String strLine1;

        while ((strLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null)
        {

            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Stream:(.*) \"(.*)\"");

            Matcher m = p.matcher(strLine1);

            while (m.find())
            {
                String inp2 = m.group(2);
                StreamMatcher.add(inp2);
                System.out.println(StreamMatcher.get(index) + " ; " + DateMatcher.get(index));
                index++;

            }

        }
        br1.close();

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(" ");
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add some other keywords for your post.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (m.find())
{
    String inp1 = m.group(0);
    DateMatcher.add(inp1);
}
```

You can add an empty string if there are no match

```
if (!m.matches()) {
    DateMatcher.add("");
} else {
    String inp1 = m.group(0);
    DateMatcher.add(inp1);
}
```

Note: Follow Java's standard naming conventions. Variable names should not start with an upper case letter.

Comment: i tried your but it does not work fine with mine,using this i am getting output something like  this : alex ;    raman ;    ali ;   jack ;

Comment: i tried your but it does not work fine with mine,using this i am getting output something like this : alex ; raman ; ali ; jack ;

Answer (score 0):

I would match using the pattern:

```
\b(\S+) and my date of birth is (\d{2}-\w{3}-\d{4})?
```

Code sample:

```
String input = "Hey my name is alex and my date of birth is 19-may-1999\nHey my name is raman and my date of birth is 21-may-1999\nHey my name is ali and my date of birth is \nHey my name is jack and my date of birth is 23-may-1999";
String pattern = "\\b(\\S+) and my date of birth is (\\d{2}-\\w{3}-\\d{4})?";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher m = r.matcher(input);
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(1) + " ; " + (m.group(2) == null ? "" : m.group(2)));
}
```

This prints:

```
alex ; 19-may-1999
raman ; 21-may-1999
ali ; 
jack ; 23-may-1999
```